# Showing members in terminal with devise and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am experiencing a strange problem, I developed a very basic app on ruby (2.0.0) on rails (4.0.0).

I am using devise gem to generate my members process, they are logging in only with email and password, and no moderation approval is required.

So I use to show the registered members with in my terminal with:

```
heroku run rails console

User.all
```

I know that it would be recommendable to use gem like active_admin to generate an admin panel.

But I'd like to understand what's wrong for now.

All the members that are registered since the 11/17 are visible. Members that registered after 11/17 are not shown in the terminal.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make any changes on that date? I'd start there. What if you create a new user with an email of what ever I example.com, then run User.where(email: "whatever I example.com") Do they show up? Are you sure you have users registered since that date? Start with the obvious.

Comment: @Pedr i checked on the date i didn't find anything, but when i run the User.where command i get this error:                      PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "supportdidlist" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (supportdidlist@hotma...) Btw i know that some people registered since that time... i checked my devise installation again, everything looks all right

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem in your `User` model.  Can you post any changes you've made in that?  And it doesn't look like you ran what @Pedr suggested.  Try: `User.where(email: 'supportdidlist@hotmail.com')`

Comment: Ok so i ran the right command as @Pedr suggested, here is what i have, #<User id: 31, email: "supportdidlist@hotmail.fr", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$zePaVbQmNGeEhy7klY6r4u4K7CrjJjhGkgNHuPVDZYzj...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 3, current_sign_in_at: "2013-11-25 23:09:46", last_sign_in_at: "2013-11-25 22:10:58", current_sign_in_ip: "84.101.235.11", last_sign_in_ip: "84.101.235.11", created_at: "2013-11-25 18:56:48", It means the email are correctly created i'm gonna check in my user model